# Run-time class instantiation based on external xml in Java

Tags: java, reflection, dependency-injection, xml-parsing, factory

I have an xml file that contains data I want to parse and read into my program so i can instantiate a class.

The problem is, which class i want to instantiate wont be known until runtime.

My xml will be a little like below.

```
<dataitem class="FooClass">
<dataitem class="BarClass">
```

Classes will all share a common interface.
At the moment i have Factory doing something like below.

```
public class FooBarFactory {
    FooBarInterface makeClass(String s){
        if(s.equals("FooClass")){
            return new FooClass();
        }
        if(s.equals("BarClass")){
            return new BarClass();
        }
}
```

In reality, there are a great many potential classes the Factory could return. Is there a way to get this sort of behaviour without having to use a conditional statement for each potential class it could be? If not,  is my thinking correct or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class FooBarFactory {
  FooBarInterface makeInstance(String s) {
    return Class.forName(s).newInstance();
  }
}
```

I didn't show it, but you will need to handle some checked exceptions such as `ClassNotFoundException`, `IllegalAccessException`, and `InstantiationException`.

Comment: @SamJudge No prob. This is mentioned in item 53 of Josh Bloch's excellent book Effective Java (2e), which I just re-read yesterday. :-)  Highly recommended.

Comment: I'll have to give it a read. I've not used much reflection in the past.

Comment: @SamJudge Incidentally, item 53 is about minimizing use of reflection.  This was one example of a rare case where it may be worthwhile despite the risks.